# How to change base dn from "dc=example,dc=org" to "ou=example,o=org" in openldap

Tags: openldap

How to change base dn from "dc=example,dc=org" to "ou=example,o=org" in openldap

This is what i have...

```
~# slapcat
dn: dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: org
dc: example
structuralObjectClass: organization
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org
```

Change to...

```
dn: ou=example,o=org
objectClass: top
objectClass: organization
o: org
objeectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: example
creatorsName: cn=admin,ou=example,o=org
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Active Directory supports single label domain names. I'm not aware of other LDAP X500 compliant products that support this. Even if there are, this is not a common or reasonable practice.

Note that X.500 is very permissive and does not require any particular naming structure. The reason the domainNameForm is nearly always hierarchical is DNS is used for name lookups, and DNS is hierarchical. (Except in the case where a DNS server has been configured to answer single label names - Microsoft).